# Properly setting the system language to English but with Swedish locale settings

Tags: kubuntu, language-support, locale

So ever since I installed Kubuntu on the computer I'm using right now I've had locale issues, which I'll admit is nothing new or unique to Ubuntu/Linux. I'm trying to set things up so that my keyboard and general locale (time, date, etc) settings are Swedish but the system language is otherwise English since that makes things so much easier.

Right now my `/etc/default/locale` looks like this:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:sv
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

And I have set KDE Plasma translations (Regional Settings -> Language) to `American English` first and `svenska[sic]` second.

Keyboard layout is also set to Swedish and works.

Under Regional Settings -> Formats I've tried setting Region to `United States - American English (en_US)` with Detailed Settings on and everything set to `Sverige - svenska (sv_SE)` there.

In Xorg everything seems to be in English as it should but in the terminal I keep running into programs that insist on Swedish output. For example:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Bra:1 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease
Bra:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Bra:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Bra:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Bra:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Läser paketlistor… Färdig
```

Does anyone know what setting I'm missing here? Surely I should be able to force this system to default to American English for the language while still retaining sane formatting for date and time?

Or is there some good alternative "en_SE" locale I can install that won't break horribly the next time I run a dist-upgrade?

Comment: Did you run `update-locale`? Have you restarted inbetween (or at least started a new shell)? Did you just manually change the settings in the file or also run `dpkg-reconfigure locales`?

Comment: I have run `update-locale` and I have rebooted, logged in and out and restarted my shell several times. I have not run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` as I was under the impression that it would wreak havoc with my config files.

Comment: What output do you get from `locale` and `sudo locale`? The one you expect?

Comment: Yes, the same as what's in `/etc/default/locale` for both.

Comment: Does e.g. perl throw an error? `echo 'print "hello world"' | perl` any problems regarding locale?

Comment: No, it seems to work as intended with no errors.

Comment: Tested it for you: run `dpgk-reconfigure locale`, `/etc/default/locale` was not affected (but feel free to back it up), language setting was applied on a new login. After that I could easily switch between three languages by just changing `/etc/default/locale` and relogin.

Comment: Tried it as well, no difference in behavior though, `LANG`, `LANGUAGE`, `LC_CTYPE` and `LC_MESSAGES` are still `en_US.UTF-8` (as they should be) but I'm getting Swedish output in both apt and Vim (in Vim `:language` is not showing `LANG` or `LANGUAGE` though). `env` shows both as set properly to `en_US.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have in `/etc/default/locale` (or more likely in your output from the `locale` command):

```
LANGUAGE=en_US:sv
```

That's wrong. `en_US` translation files are usually empty, since `en_US` is the original language. And when `gettext` does not find an `en_US` translation for a string, it falls back to Swedish in some cases.

So change that somehow to:

```
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
```

Comment: could repoduce and confirm

Comment: This does appear to have been the issue. However, I also had to edit `~/.config/plasma-localerc` and restart Xorg because even after changing `/etc/default/locale` the old setting persisted after logging out and in again.

Comment: @GomerPyle: Yeah, I was intentionally vague about how to do it exactly, since I don't use KDE. Good that you figured it out.

Comment: A similar answer here: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181857/the-language-locale-variable-how-to-set-english-as-primary-language-a-bug-i](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181857/the-language-locale-variable-how-to-set-english-as-primary-language-a-bug-i)

Comment: @okoloBasii: Yes. But to me those answers are rather confusing.