# Problem - Changing keyboard language layout in Kubuntu 20.04 also changes wide system language

Tags: kubuntu, keyboard-layout, language-support

I'm using Kubuntu 20.04 with KDE 5.68.0 and Plasma 5.18.5.

I live in Argentina and like to have my OSs in English, but I own a Spanish keyboard.

So, I naturally installed Kubuntu in English and then went to **System Settings > Input Devices**, and at the **Layouts** tab added a Spanish keyboard layout.
Everything worked fine until I rebooted.

Now my system is completely in Spanish. But if I go to **System Settings > Regional Setting > Language** the only shown item is "American English".

Even more awkward, if I now add as a new system language "español de España", but not as default language, and reboot, the system returns to English, but some terminal messages and apps (like Crossover) appear in Spanish!!

This is driving me nuts.
Any ideas???

Edit: Just checked my **/etc/default/locale** and it has the following content:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
```

**sudo locale** show this output:

```
LANG=es_AR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:es
LC_CTYPE="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="es_AR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

There are some entries with **es_AR**, but don't know why is it so.

Comment: I don't think the additional keyboard layout has anything to do with it. But does this answer your question? [Properly setting the system language to English but with Swedish locale settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311472/properly-setting-the-system-language-to-english-but-with-swedish-locale-settings)

Comment: Your `locale` output shows that you seem to have the same issue as in that other question. But in addition to that, you somehow have set `LANG=es_AR.UTF-8`. You need to check your KDE settings.

Comment: Here's a partial list of files you should check https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/56044/5223